# Laravel update or delete in sql multiselect field

Tags: sql, laravel, select, eloquent

I have multiselect option in my website.

```
<select multiple name="genres[]">
<option value="1">action</option>
<option value="2">adult</option>
<option value="3">advanture</option>
<option value="4">anime</option>
<option value="5">biographic</option>
</select>
```

Also i have fields in db
shows

```
id  name
1   grey's anatomy
2   the morning show
```

genres

```
id  name
1   action
2   adult
3   advanture
3   anime
5   biographic
```

data_show_genres

```
id  show_id   genre_id
1   1         4
2   1         2
3   2         1
```

After Submit button, function do

```
foreach ($input['genres'] as $genre) {
 DataShowGenres::updateOrCreate(
   ['show_id' => $id, 'genre_id' => $genre]
 );
}
```

So adding work's, but when i try to remove, i mean unselect some data. Old still stays. I can always delete old data for that show but is there any way to do this better?

Edit:
Controller:

```
public function edit_update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'title'     => 'required|min:1|max:300',
            'imdb'      => 'required|min:0|max:10000000|numeric',
            'tvdb'      => 'required|min:0|max:10000000|numeric',
            'youtube'   => 'nullable|url',
            'hidden'    => 'nullable',
        ]);
        $input = $request->all();
        $input['hidden']    = $request->has('hidden') ? 1 : 0;
        $input['recommend'] = $request->has('recommend') ? 1 : 0;
        if (empty($input["genres"])) {
        } else {
            foreach ($input['genres'] as $genre) {
                $zanr = DataShowGenres::updateOrCreate(
                    ['show_id' => $id, 'genre_id' => $genre]
                );
            }
        }
        $serija              = Serija::FindOrFail($id_serije);
        $serija->title       = $input['title'];
        $serija->imdb        = $input['imdb'];
        $serija->tvdb        = $input['tvdb'];
        $serija->imdb_rating = $input['imdb_rating'];
        $serija->tmdb        = $input['tmdb'];
        $serija->hidden      = $input['hidden'];
        $serija->youtube     = $input['youtube'];
        $serija->save();
        toast('Edited!', 'success');
        return back();
    }
```

Route:

```
Route::get('/serije/izmeni/{id}/{slug}', 'SerijeController@edit')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'title' => '^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$'])->middleware('permission:show_edit');
Route::post('/serije/izmeni/{id}/{slug}', 'SerijeController@edit_update')->where(['id' => '[0-9]+', 'naziv' => '^[a-z0-9]+(?:-[a-z0-9]+)*$'])->middleware('permission:show_edit');
```

Comment: Please add full code including blade , routes and controller

Comment: @FouedMOUSSI i added more files. I wasn't add blade becouse form is working okej, i checked widh dd($request), it send everything okay. My problem is updating db. I try to genres be belongsToMany and everything but i don't know to do that, so i make models for data where is show_is and genre_id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[Syncing Associations](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships)**

> You may use the sync method to construct many-to-many
>   associations. The sync method accepts an array of IDs to place on the
>   intermediate table. Any IDs that are not in the given array will be
>   removed from the intermediate table. So, after this operation is
>   complete, only the IDs in the given array will exist in the
>   intermediate table:

```
//...
$show = Show::findOrFail($id);
$show->genres()->sync($input['genres']);
//...
```

Comment: That's worked.Thank you. I need to change my codewith pivot table and everything that, but sync then worked for genres. Thank you. :)